# Add field to vocabulary itself

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

I have a situation where I would like to add a field to a vocabulary itself.  In other words, I need an editable field on the form that normally appears at `/admin/structure/taxonomy/my_vocabulary/edit` and not a field that appears each term in the vocabulary.  Unfortunately, the `description` column in `{taxonomy_vocabulary}` is too limited for what I need.

What is the best way to go about this?  If possible I would like to avoid making a custom module with a custom table, form-alters for the vocabulary edit page, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the basic problem is that a vocabulary is not fieldable. In theory this is easy to fix, but I don't know if they lack this functionality because it would cause technical difficulties, or to avoid confusion users.

To make a vocabulary fieldable, implement [hook_entity_info_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7):

```
function hook_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
  $entity_info['taxonomy_vocabulary']['fieldable'] = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: +1 That's a great answer...looking at the controller classes ([`TaxonomyVocabularyController`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/class/TaxonomyVocabularyController/7) and [`TaxonomyTermController`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/class/TaxonomyTermController/7)) there's not much difference so nothing to suggest fields wouldn't work out of the box.

Comment: If I go with this, I assume I would have to wire up everything to add fields via the UI myself?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that question. Obviously you need to "add the field yourself", but it wouldn't need to happen through the UI. You could add field programmatically.

Comment: @Letharion, thanks.  I'm just trying to make things as simple as possible for an odd request that came in on a project.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Fieldable vocabularies](http://drupal.org/project/fieldable_vocabularies) module.

> This module exposes the Vocabulary to the field system. It defines a single bundle and a single view mode.